# Alinear el contenido de un JTextArea a la izquierda

Tags: java, java-swing

¡Hola!
Como podría alinear el contenido de un JTextArea a la izquierda?
He probado con un

```
setAlignmentY(this.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
```

Pero parece no funcionar.

Gracias, un saludo!

Comment: Creo que deberías más bien utilizar `setAlignmentX()` que establece una alineación Horizontal. Cuando digo Horizontal, me refiero al eje X, este sería de izquierda a derecha.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
jTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
```

Comment: Intenta explicar que hace el código que has añadido para que lo entienda mejor el OP y los futuros usuarios.